# Django installation issue

Tags: django

I've just begun learning Django.
I ran the following command to install Django:

```
1. download and unpack Django-2.1.5.tar.gz in /u01
2. cd /u01/Python-3.7.2/bin
3. ./python3 -m venv ./python3 -m venv /u01/django  
4. source /u01/django/bin/activate
5. cd /u01/django/bin
6. ./pip3 install -e /u01/Django-2.1.5  
Obtaining file:///u01/Django-2.1.5
Collecting pytz (from Django==2.1.5)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe464ed25c0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytz/
...
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe464ed2278>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytz/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz (from Django==2.1.5) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pytz (from Django==2.1.5)
```

So I downloaded and installed the latest pytz-2018.9:

```
$ cd /u01/Python-3.7.2/bin
$  ./pip3 install ../../pytz-2018.9
Processing /home/alelai/pytz-2018.9
Installing collected packages: pytz
  Running setup.py install for pytz ... done
Successfully installed pytz-2018.9
```

and reran step 2-6 above. the same error occured.

Comment: It's better to install using pip inside virtualenv

Comment: If you're doing an offline install of Django, you're going to need to get `pytz` first since it is a dependency.

Comment: I have never install this way Django, But you don't have the dependency pytz installed, instead of downloading executable or binaries use pip install Django

Comment: This will help you : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/install/

Comment: I hvae to downlod the package since I'm doing the installation in my home directory on a company server which has no external internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solve after setting PYTHONPATH to the pytz location